# Why do I have to specify a length when converting numeric to Unicode in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to convert a numeric column in Oracle to a string padded with leading zeros. The problem I'm having is I can convert to a Unicode value just fine, but I have to specify the length when I do that. The total length will be 9 with the zeros. If the number is only 7 or 8 digits, I have to add zeros.

The problem is: when I cast the numeric to WSTR in my derived column block, I have to specify the length. If I specify the length as 9, my code for padding zeros doesn't work. I'm assuming because it thinks it is already 9 characters long. I added a call to TRIM in the expression, hoping that it would shorten the value to 7 or 8 and then pad the zeros, but that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Here's the expression I'm working on right now:

```
ISNULL([CERT_NUM]) ? "" :  REPLICATE( "0", 9 - LEN((DT_WSTR, 9)[CERT_NUM] )) + (DT_WSTR, 9)[CERT_NUM]
```

Solution from answer below:

```
ISNULL(CERT_NUM) ? "" : RIGHT(REPLICATE("0",9) + (DT_WSTR,9)(DT_I4)CERT_NUM,9)
```

I cast the numeric column to an int to drop the decimal, cast to string with length of 9, concatenated 9 zeros and took the right 9 characters.

Comment: Huh? Perhaps if you provided the expression you are using, my simple brain my grok you better

Comment: As you can see in my expression, to convert a numeric to a string, you have to specify the length. But, that's weird to me because the number of digits won't be the same. I know the max width will be 9, but what about shorter values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach to left padding content is to put it all together and then grab the right N bits

```
RIGHT((REPLICATE("0",9) + (DT_WSTR,9)[SourceColumn]), 9)
```

I build an all zero string, concatenate that with my SourceColumn and then throw away all but the last 9 characters. Similar to your code but simpler because I don't care what the original length was.

The other thing I can see is you get to deal with nullable columns and you've already identified that you'll use the ternary operator to handle that.

```
(IsNull([SourceColumn])) ? 
    "" 
    : RIGHT((REPLICATE("0",9) + (DT_WSTR,9)[SourceColumn]), 9)
```

Another thing to simply be aware of is that some times you will need to add another explicit cast to the whole expression. Something about the ternary operator will just get confused changing data types

```
(DT_WSTR, 9)((IsNull([SourceColumn])) ? 
    "" 
    : RIGHT((REPLICATE("0",9) + (DT_WSTR,9)[SourceColumn]), 9))
```

I can't address the why aspect of your question.

Regardless of the source columns total digits, you will want to cast to the maximum length.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Not a genius, just do a bit of [ssis](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssis/topusers) ;) You were on the right track, just overthinking your problem